# How to use two events onItemSelect and onItemDeselect in AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect.
http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

And I want to use both the events. But don't know how to configure both. I am able to configure only one of them successfully.

```
onItemSelect(property)
```

and

```
onItemDeselect(property)
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="property.dropdowns" selected-model="property.propertyValues"
                            extra-settings="multiSelectDropdownSettingsMaxOne" ng-required="property.startDate != null" events="onItemSelect(property)"></div>
```

**Update**

I tried like this with comma separator but got error

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="property.dropdowns" selected-model="property.propertyValues" extra-settings="multiSelectDropdownSettingsMaxOne" ng-required="property.startDate != null" events="onItemSelect(property), onItemDeSelect(property)"></div>
```

Comment: did you tried ';' semicolon ?

Comment: @SourabhAgrawal Super mate it worked like charm.. you are the star.

Comment: Can u pls post java script code also. I am having same problem and enable to call function in java script.

Comment: Could not figure out either. Answer by @Francisco Cuello works better

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
$scope.yourEvents = {onInitDone: function(item) {console.log(item);},onItemDeselect: function(item) {console.log(item);}};

<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="YourData" events="yourEvents" 
 selected-model="YourModel" extra-settings="yourSettings">
</div>
```

[[source](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/39)]

Comment: Ok, I forgot to include the source :(

Comment: Hi, I want to add the button click event for this https://jsfiddle.net/michaeldeongreen/22et6sao/9/  can you tell me how to set it. I have create event but it is not hitting can you resolve me